# Trigger mouse leave when animated sprite is clicked

Tags: css, animation, hover, sprite

I have a link containing a sprite image, with a CSS animation on mouse hover.

```
a {
    display:inline-block;
    width:48px;
    height:48px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

a img {
    -webkit-transition: 250ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: 250ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: 250ms ease-out;
    transition: 250ms ease-out;
}

a:hover img{
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(0,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0,-50%);
    -o-transform: translate(0,-50%);
    transform: translate(0,-50%);
}
```

Animation works fine, but when I click the link, it remains on hover state.

Here's a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/1jyskpae/1/) showing the problem. When you click the link, a new tab is opened as expected. But when you come back to the fiddle, the sprite is still in hover state. How can I bring it back to normal (not-hover) state? I've tried to trigger `mouseleave` event with jQuery, but it failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event is fired correctly but the CSS still sees it as ':hover' state (and I don't think you can change that with javascript). Therefore you could change your css from

```
a:hover img {
```

to

```
a.hovered img {
```

thus setting it as a class on its own and not a css state. Then in your JS you can leave the click handler as before (even though I used 'mouseout' but it shouldn't matter) and add a hover() handler like

```
$('a').click(function() {    
    $(this).trigger('mouseout');    
});

$('a').hover(function() {    
    $(this).addClass('hovered');
}, function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hovered');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Customize hover behavior with jQuery instead of CSS `:hover` pseudo class:

```
<a id='theLink' href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://bradsknutson.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/facebook-hover.png" alt="Facebook"/></a>

a {
    display:inline-block;
    width:48px;
    height:48px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

a img {
    -webkit-transition: 250ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: 250ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: 250ms ease-out;
    transition: 250ms ease-out;
}

.hover{
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(0,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0,-50%);
    -o-transform: translate(0,-50%);
    transform: translate(0,-50%);
}

$('#theLink').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).children().first().addClass('hover');
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).children().first().removeClass('hover');
}).click(function(){
    $(this).children().first().removeClass('hover');
});
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/gssw0dm6/